# AngularJS — directive $parsing an evaluated expression onto the scope object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am passing a string to my isolated directive with the `@` scope configuration, hoping to be able to get that string as an object on the scope, which could then be assigned a value.

HTML

```
<div directive model="object.property.property"></div>
```

JS

```
directive('directive', function($parse) {
    scope: {
        model: '@' 
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        var object = $parse(scope.model);
        object(scope);
        scope.object.property.property = 'newstring';
        // scope.object.property.property = 'newstring';
    }
});
```

I was hoping that this would allow me to get `object.property.property` onto the scope with a value of `newstring`.

It doesn't seem that I am using the `$parse` service correctly, but most of the examples I am finding are related to using `$parse` to convert JSON. How can I use parse to turn this string into an object on the directive's scope?

Thanks!

Comment: are you trying to change the value of model in the directive ?

Comment: Yes! Once the model is on the scope you could do all kinds of things to it in the linking function. :-)

Comment: the entire purpose of the `@` is to do **text** binding, not **object** binding.  why can't you use the `=` in the scope?

Comment: I'm trying to evaluate some items on the parent scope and then add some properties in the attribute, like ```<div directive model="{{objectFromParent}}.propertyDeclaredHere">```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
app.directive("mainDir", function($parse) {
  return {
     restrict: 'AE',
     scope: {
       model: '@'
     }
    template: '<div> hello: {{model}} </div>',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
       el.on('click', function(evt) {
           evt.stopPropagation();
           evt.preventDefault();
           var object = $parse(attrs.model);
           scope.$apply(function() {
               object(scope);
           });
           object = 'new string';
           scope.model = object;
       })
  }
 }
})
```

Usage:

```
<div main-dir model="object.property.property"></div>
```

Comment: Hm thanks for reaching out! Not exactly. I simply want to make the string ```object.property.property``` available on the scope, so that it could be used in the scope to have values etc assigned to it. So if you had ```<div directive model="object.property.property"></div>``` you could get ```scope.object.property.property``` in the scope or if you had  ```<div directive model="joke"></div>``` you could get ```scope.joke``` available in the scope to assign values to it. :-)

Comment: So you want to dynamically add more properties to the isolated scope object? hmmm, not sure if it is possible tho

Comment: Would adding them through html attributes be considered 'dynamic'? Hmm. $parsing doesn't allow properties to be added to the scope object?

Comment: Let say you have a template like this: <div your-directive model="model" other-model="other model" other-model-again="model again"></div> Then in your directive, you will have isolated scope like this: scope : {model : '@', otherModel:'@', otherModelAgain:'@'}

Comment: I don't think you can somehow do like this: scope.push(myOtherModel) then you go to html template and use: <div my-directive myOtherModel="my other model"> </div>

Comment: Hmm. What a shame! Thanks for the help. Will leave the question open in case any one else knows any methods :-)